# Angular app on IOS doesn't show me keyboard, when i click on input. Why?

Tags: ios, angularjs, input, keyboard

My Angular application doesn't show me keyboard, when i click on input for the first time. Second click and other shows it.
I don't have ngTouch and any function on inputs.

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="email" name="login" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" ng-model="form.userData.login" placeholder="{{'LOGIN_OR_EMAIL' | translate}}" required>
</div>
```

Nothing special in html

Comment: I am not sure, but this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776118/tapping-text-input-field-on-iphone-brings-up-keyboard-but-typing-will-not-put-i

Comment: @SachinKariyattin unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

if you have

> -webkit-user-select:none;
>            user-select:none;

in your css remove them.